# Plugin Base64 doesn't work on ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, base64, sanitization

I'm working on Ionic 3, I'm geting the Url for the Image's user profile, I saving the file on a directory and save the path on the BD.

I need to convert the file to base64 and then sanitize but it show me in console the next message `plugin_not_installed`. I'm going crazy, I need their help

```
convertTobase64(){
     this.base64Image = 'C:\\Users\\Antonio\\Source\\Workspaces\\Ringer Tour\\RT.Api\\Data\\Tourist\\1\\image5204.jpg';

     this.base64.encodeFile(this.base64Image).then((base64File: string) => {
         this.base64Img = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(base64File);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: I only put the public URL in where are saved my Image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ionicframeworks [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) plugin. The method **readAsDataURL** will help to read file from given location and return data as a base64 encoded data url.

Comment: Thanks, I'm researching about this method, I hope that works, Jacob

Comment: I've been researching and you're rigth, but I can't convert my file path to blob, Do you know some for this, thanks a lot

Comment: @AntonioPosadaMagdaleno I don't understand. what do you mean by converting file path to blob. Also, please mention the purpose. Maybe, I should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there are two functions respectively for decoding and encoding base64 strings:

1) atob()
2) btoa()

The atob() function decodes a string of data which has been encoded using base-64 encoding. Conversely, the btoa() function creates a base-64 encoded ASCII string from a "string" of binary data.

```
convertTobase64(){
    this.base64Image = 'C:\\Users\\Antonio\\Source\\Workspaces\\Ringer Tour\\RT.Api\\Data\\Tourist\\1\\image5204.jpg';

    var str: string;
    str = btoa(this.base64Image);     
}
```

Try this, I did this in my project to convert password in base64 string.
You don't need to install any plugins for this.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and this function efectly convert the string to base64, but doesn't convert the file, only the path and I can´t show it on html as image, I need convert not the path, need encoding the file.

Comment: @AntonioPosadaMagdaleno still the same error? do i need to give you the whole code to set the profile picture? I have already done this in my project.